# Getting random command-line args when compiling and debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

So I'm making an example program to learn how to build and debug C projects in Visual Studio Code. For reference, here's my `launch.json` and `tasks.json` for the project:

**launch.json:**

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "test-project",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\test.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "build test-project"
    }
]
```

**tasks.json:**

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build test-project",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gcc",
        "args": [
            "-std=c99",
            "-g",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\test.c",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceRoot}\\test.exe"              
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

And here's 'test.c':

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


    int t = 9;
    int p = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I see for my command-line arguments even though I gave no command-line arguments:

[image]

There turns out to be 3 extra command-line arguments `"2>CON"`, `"1>CON"`, and `"<CON"` as you can see in the watch panel. Why is this happening even though I gave 0 command-line arguments?

Comment: Those look like redirections for file descriptors.  `2>CON` redirects stderr to CON, `1>CON` redirects stdout to CON, and `<CON` redirects stdin from CON.  It looks like something is adding those to `argv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and testing in Visual Studio Code, I discovered an option called `"externalConsole"` within `launch.json` that redirects output to an actual command prompt window, removing the additional re-directions from the command-line. There's also another option called `"avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection"` that avoids adding the extra command-line arguments/re-directions without an external command-prompt displaying. If both options are present within your `launch.json` file, `"externalConsole"` takes precedence. Example of using both below:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "test-project",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\test.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "build test-project"

    }
]
```