# MinGW gdb in vs code - passes 4 arguments into main(), when I expect only 1?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

If I try to debug the code in vs code using mingw gdb on windows 11, main() receives 4 arguments, not the 1 I expect
If I run the compiled code (not using gdb), then only 1 argument received as expected

If I run the same project in vs code on my chromebook, then when debugged using gdb, only 1 argument received as expected
(debian install of g++)

So, I believe it's an issue with running mingw gdb from vs code in windows 10
But I have no idea why?

The four arguments received are below, obviously I expected the first one only...

```
C:\Users\David\source\repos\david284\basic-cpp-example/main.exe
2>CON
1>CON
<CON
```

The configuration to launch gdb is below...
I believe there aren't any arguments defined

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "",
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```

Comment: What are the 3 additional arguments?

Comment: Edited original post to add all four arguments

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61177891/1983398)?

Answer (score 0):

Answered by the link given by ssbssa